# The underlying connection was closed exception while WebClient DownloadString

Tags: c#, webclient, downloadstring

Just a piece of code

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
String str = wc.DownloadString(new Uri("http://content.warframe.com/dynamic/rss.php"));
```

And I got exception:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in
>   System.dll
>
> Additional information: The underlying connection was closed: The
>   connection was closed unexpectedly.

I've head that this is a bug in .NET (I am using 3.5), but I tried other methods to obtain the content of this link (its rss, xml). No lucky shot yet

```
var webrequest = (WebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(@"http://content.warframe.com/dynamic/rss.php");
var resp = webrequest.GetResponse();
//HttpWebResponse webresponse = (HttpWebResponse)webrequest.GetResponse(); // Wont work also
```

This code above won't work either, both casts the same exception

**Fiddler logs:**

SESSION STATE: Aborted.
Response Entity Size: 512 bytes.

== FLAGS ==================
BitFlags: [ResponseGeneratedByFiddler] 0x100
X-ABORTED-WHEN: Done
X-CLIENTIP: 127.0.0.1
X-CLIENTPORT: 2747
X-EGRESSPORT: 2748
X-FAILSESSION-WHEN: ReadingResponse
X-HOSTIP: 205.185.216.10
X-PROCESSINFO: willitwork.vshost:3300

== TIMING INFO ============
ClientConnected:    10:29:11.706
ClientBeginRequest: 10:29:11.713
GotRequestHeaders:  10:29:11.713
ClientDoneRequest:  10:29:11.713
Determine Gateway:  0ms
DNS Lookup:         164ms
TCP/IP Connect: 74ms
HTTPS Handshake:    0ms
ServerConnected:    10:29:11.953
FiddlerBeginRequest:    10:29:11.953
ServerGotRequest:   10:29:11.953
ServerBeginResponse:    10:29:12.372
GotResponseHeaders: 00:00:00.000
ServerDoneResponse: 10:29:12.372
ClientBeginResponse:    10:29:12.385
ClientDoneResponse: 10:29:12.385

Overall Elapsed:    0:00:00.672

The response was buffered before delivery to the client.

== WININET CACHE INFO ============
This URL is not present in the WinINET cache. [Code: 2]
* Note: Data above shows WinINET's current cache state, not the state at the time of the request.
* Note: Data above shows WinINET's Medium Integrity (non-Protected Mode) cache only.

Also - 504, this does not makes sense since I can get data from link via chrome / firefox / ie...

I just did it to work in other language, but I am forced to do it with C# (I' ve made 2 much code to rewrite it)

I've added some settings like fiddler said

```
myHttpWebRequest1.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version11;
myHttpWebRequest1.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36";
myHttpWebRequest1.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8";
```

At least now I get 504 error instead of "unknown", but I can still view the content via webbrowser, so the 504 error is **fake**

Edit: There is no response error when I added

```
myHttpWebRequest1.Headers["Accept-Encoding"] = "gzip";
```

but now the output is messed and unreadable

Comment: Don't conclude too quickly that this is a BCL bug. The fact that changing the request headers results in a different error is strong evidence that the server just didn't like what you sent.

Comment: I am trying to send that what was sent by my webbrowser (at least headers). I always follow the rule that the code works in the way you' ve wrote it.

Comment: After installing patch https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3042058 we received this message when using SSL (TLS 1.0) under .Net Framework 3.5. Removing the update fixed the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, i got this all fixes & working!

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Uri url = new Uri(@"http://content.warframe.com/dynamic/rss.php");

    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

    // MAGIC LINE GOES HERE \/
    request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;

    // Assign the response object of HttpWebRequest to a HttpWebResponse variable.
    using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
    {
        using (Stream streamResponse = response.GetResponseStream())
        {
            using (StreamReader streamRead = new StreamReader(streamResponse))
            {
                Char[] readBuff = new Char[2000];
                int count = streamRead.Read(readBuff, 0, 2000);
                while (count > 0)
                {
                    String outputData = new String(readBuff, 0, count);
                    Console.Write(outputData);
                    count = streamRead.Read(readBuff, 0, 2000);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Besides of not-using **WebClient.DownloadString** method i had to add *decompresion* line

```
request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;
```

Thanks for tips (especially fiddler one, Decode button saved my time to find what's wrong)

Comment: And do you know how is it possible that the code worked without any problem from my home computer and you had to decompress? It is public web site so it should work the same way for me and for you?

Comment: It must be configured on client side I think, I was looking for answer and I only found notes about IIS configuration. Since in Windows 7 I don't ve IIS installed by default I did it manually, and it shows that I don't have installed module for dynamic compression (php in this case). I am not an expert in web stuff, and I think that IIS is wrong place to look for answer...

Comment: Didn't work for me.  I still got:


The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.
InnerException = {"Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream."}

Answer (score 3):

I have same error.

You can add **User Agent** to your *httpRequest*

```
request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/15.0.874.121 Safari/535.2";
```

Answer (score 2):

Check this answer:

[..The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21728773/the-underlying-connection-was-closed-an-unexpected-error-occurred-on-a-receiv)

So this may work for you:

```
var webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(@"http://content.warframe.com/dynamic/rss.php");
webRequest.KeepAlive = false;
var resp = webRequest.GetResponse();
```

### EDIT:

You are right, check rather this:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.keepalive%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Here is working code that will print out the recieved response content:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
          // Create a new HttpWebRequest object.Make sure that 
          // a default proxy is set if you are behind a firewall.
          HttpWebRequest myHttpWebRequest1 =
            (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(@"http://content.warframe.com/dynamic/rss.php");

          myHttpWebRequest1.KeepAlive=false;
          // Assign the response object of HttpWebRequest to a HttpWebResponse variable.
          HttpWebResponse myHttpWebResponse1 = 
            (HttpWebResponse)myHttpWebRequest1.GetResponse();

          Console.WriteLine("\nThe HTTP request Headers for the first request are: \n{0}", myHttpWebRequest1.Headers);

          Stream streamResponse = myHttpWebResponse1.GetResponseStream();
          StreamReader streamRead = new StreamReader(streamResponse);
          Char[] readBuff = new Char[256];
          int count = streamRead.Read(readBuff, 0, 256);
          Console.WriteLine("The contents of the Html page are.......\n");
          while (count > 0)
          {
              String outputData = new String(readBuff, 0, count);
              Console.Write(outputData);
              count = streamRead.Read(readBuff, 0, 256);
          }
          Console.WriteLine();
          // Close the Stream object.
          streamResponse.Close();
          streamRead.Close();
          Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Comment: WebRequest do not have KeepAlive method, the link didn't help me cuz I don't understand how to implement his code into mine

Comment: Nope, still not working. I've turned off firewall, restarted my computer in case of non-closed streams, I even changed my IP... still the same problem. GetResponse() fails

Comment: On my computer this code is working perfectly using .NET 3.5 as you do. It seems your problem lies elsewhere. Do you get the response using normal browser? If yes, try to make simple Console App using the code provided above and see if it is working. Also try to add myHttpWebRequest1.ProtocolVersion=HttpVersion.Version10;

Comment: Another option is to debug your requests using Fiddler.

Comment: I was googling about fiddler but I will have to learn this a little
It won't work on my PC, laptop, and friend's PC, but this can be compilation error or sth

Comment: Fiddler will automatically inject itself for web browsers, but you have to add it as a proxy for other, hand-rolled apps.