# How to use a proxy with webclient.downloadstring vb.net

Tags: vb.net, proxy, webclient

I'm trying to use webclient via a proxy. I've got the following two attempts at doing so:

```
 Dim wc As WebClient = New WebClient()
 wc.Proxy = New System.Net.WebProxy(proxyadd(currentprox), True)
 Dim html As String
 html = wc.DownloadString(URL)
```

And...

```
 Dim wc As WebClient = New WebClient()
 Dim prox As New WebProxy(proxyadd(currentprox))
 prox.Address = New Uri(proxyadd(currentprox))
 wc.Proxy = prox
 Dim html As String
 html = wc.DownloadString(URL)
```

Where proxyadd(currentprox) is an address in the form: "157.122.114.153:9000" (variable type is string).

The error I get when trying to use any proxy is:

> The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on
>   a receive.

Any advice/help would be great. I found [this](http://www.ultraproxies.com/high-anonymous.html) list of proxies that I plan on using.

Comment: What's the amount of data retrieved? In addition, how long does it take, could it be a timeout?

Comment: Also, please have a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21728773/the-underlying-connection-was-closed-an-unexpected-error-occurred-on-a-receiv

Comment: The amount of data is small, I've tried it with the url of a google search and still get the issue.