# C# : System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed

Tags: c#, .net, rest, http

I have the following code :

```
String url = // a valid url
String requestXml = File.ReadAllText(filePath);//opens file , reads all text and closes it
byte[] bytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(requestXml);
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("DEFAULT\\Admin", "Admin"); 
request.ContentType = "application/xml";
request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
request.Method = "POST";
request.KeepAlive = false;
Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
requestStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
requestStream.Close();
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
return new StreamReader(responseStream).ReadToEnd();
```

During run-time, I'm getting the following exception while trying to read the `HTTPWebResponse` :

> System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive.
>   ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine.
>   ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
>         at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
>         at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
>         at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
>          at System.Net.PooledStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
>          at System.Net.Connection.SyncRead(HttpWebRequest request, Boolean userRetrievedStream, Boolean probeRead)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21728773/the-underlying-connection-was-closed-an-unexpected-error-occurred-on-a-receiv

Comment: @w0051977 I have seen this thread already, i'm already setting request.keepAlive = false. So is it necessary to override the GetWebRequest(Uri uri) method?

Comment: Remove the Close() method and try again.  You are trying to read a response from a connection that you closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't close the stream before reading from it. This should work:

```
String url = // a valid url
String requestXml = File.ReadAllText(filePath);//opens file , reads all text and closes it
byte[] bytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(requestXml);
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("DEFAULT\\Admin", "Admin"); 
request.ContentType = "application/xml";
request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
request.Method = "POST";
request.KeepAlive = false;
using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
{
    requestStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
    {
        using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
        {
            using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
            {
                return streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Adding this line of code solved the problem for me:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

This was taken from: https://our.umbraco.com/forum/using-umbraco-and-getting-started/74628-the-underlying-connection-was-closed-an-unexpected-error-occurred-on-a-send

Answer (score 0):

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(url);
    httpResponse = client.GetAsync(url).Result;
}
```

Try this