# TwitterService.GetRequestToken throws exception "Value cannot be null. Parameter name: query"

Tags: c#, twitter, tweetsharp

An week ago I faced a problem with getting request token from TweetSharp library, every time it throws null exception. Previously it works, credentials are valid. The same problem with test from https://github.com/shugonta/tweetsharp
Looks like again some problem with TweetSharp proxy.

```
var service = new TwitterService(_consumerKey, _consumerSecret);
var requestToken = service.GetRequestToken();

System.ArgumentNullException : Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: query
   at System.Compat.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(String query, Encoding encoding) in D:\My Dropbox\_7_Source_Code\_1_Projects\hammock-codeplex\src\net40\Hammock.ClientProfile\Mono\HttpUtility.cs:line 1222
   at TweetSharp.TwitterService.GetRequestToken(String callback) in C:\Users\Boker\Desktop\tweetsharp-master\src\net40\TweetSharp.Next\Service\TwitterService.OAuth.cs:line 171
   at TweetSharp.TwitterService.GetRequestToken() in C:\Users\Boker\Desktop\tweetsharp-master\src\net40\TweetSharp.Next\Service\TwitterService.OAuth.cs:line 184
   at TweetSharp.Tests.Service.TwitterServiceTests.Can_exchange_for_access_token() in C:\Users\Boker\Desktop\tweetsharp-master\src\net40\TweetSharp.Next.Tests\Service\TwitterServiceTests.OAuth.cs:line 26
```

Answer (score 5):

Calling GetRequestToken returns an exception.  I then reviewed TwitterService.Response and found this exception: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.  Solution reference:  [..The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21728773/the-underlying-connection-was-closed-an-unexpected-error-occurred-on-a-receiv)

Thus, add this before calling a TweetSharp method.

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
```

Comment: Worked like  charm and saved so much of time

Comment: SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 is sufficient

Comment: Namespace is System.Net