# underlying connection was closed. an unexpected error occurs on receive

Tags: c#, vb.net, web-scraping

I am getting page source using HTTPwebrequest from website  for every 5 seconds. It works well and getting page source perfectly after nearly 20 minutes, it continuously throws an exception "underlying connection was closed. an unexpected error occurs on receive" in request.GetResponse() and not receiving page source.
Also set ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 Or SecurityProtocolType.Tls Or SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 Or SecurityProtocolType.Tls12.
Any help pls.

Comment: I know tagged as C# but does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21728773/the-underlying-connection-was-closed-an-unexpected-error-occurred-on-a-receiv  You may also find the problem is at the other end, so may not be a problem you can resolve

Comment: i resolved the issue . Thank You